# Find point on a sphere given two angles

Tags: geometry, spheres

I have a direction represented as two angles `x` (angle around x axis), and `y` (angle around y axis). A ray from the origin moving in this direction will intersect a sphere with a radius of 1 that is centered at the origin at some coordinates. How can I find these coordinates? I would prefer a solution that doesn't require rotation matrices.

Comment: What direction are you starting in?  Not [1,0,0], since then your first rotation would do nothing.

Comment: Which axis is which in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are starting at $(0,0,1)$ since that seems to make the most sense for an $x$-$y$ rotation.

If you rotate about the $x$-axis by some angle $\theta_x$, then you've rotated your point from $(0, 0,1)$ to 
$$
(0 , \cos(\theta_x) , \sin(\theta_x) )
$$
and if you follow that by a rotation of $\theta_y$ about $y$-axis then you have 
$$
(\sin(\theta_x) \cdot \sin(\theta_y), \cos(\theta_x), \sin(\theta_x) \cos(\theta_y) )
$$

Answer (score 0):

if $\theta$ is the angle around the $x$ axis and $\phi$ is the angle around the $y$ axis.

Suppose $(x,y,z)$ is the point on the unit sphere.

$(x,y,z)\cdot (1,0,0) = x = \cos \theta\\
(x,y,z)\cdot (0,1,0) = y = \cos \phi\\
z = \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta - \cos^2\phi}$

Comment: Are the angles used in your answer in degrees or radians?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: I am not sure whether it matters, so I will just try either way to see which works for me.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: I wrote a program to test if it works with degrees. If the `x`-axis angle is 9, and the `y`-axis angle is 45, `z` will be the square root of a negative number, which shows up as NaN. In my program, `x` is `cos(angle x)`, `y` is `cos(angle y)`, and `z` is `sqrt(1 - cos^2(angle x) - cos^2(angle y))`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is no point on the surface such that a ray from the origin to the surface forms an angle of $9$ degrees with the $x$ axis and $45$ degrees with the $y$ axis.  Hence a complex (or NaN) $z$ would be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43440/discussion-between-pengowen123-and-doug-m).